# Angular cli not installing on windows 10

Tags: angular, angular5

I tried all things

- `npm cache clean`
- `npm cache verify`
- deleting npm-cache folders manually

As suggested in StackOverflow question.
But none worked

Please see the screen attached.

[image]

Comment: why downvote ? , its the issue, i tried all things available but couldn't find the solution, maybe this will help someone.

Answer (score -1):

please remove node_module with this command

`rm node_module`

run this command:

`npm install -g @angular/cli`

and reinstall node_modules

Comment: npm cache clean --force and npm install -g @angular/cli
it works well.